# save a list of table data into database in jsp

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I am trying to save a table which looks like below. 
The problem is, when i am saving the first record of the table only inserting into the database.

Please suggest me how to save all the rows data into database.

The table in **view page** is as

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><input type="checkbox" name="check" id="flowcheckall" value="1"></th>
            <th>Level of education</th>
            <th>college name</th>
            <th>university name</th>
            <th>year of passing</th>                
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="dataTable">
        <%  
            int i = 0;
            for(i=0;i<eduDetails.size();i++) { 
            HashMap EduDet = new HashMap();
            EduDet = (HashMap)eduDetails.get(i);
        %>      
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="check_list" class="check_list" id="<% out.print(EduDet.get("s.no")); %>" value="<% out.print(EduDet.get("s.no")); %>" style="width:10px"></td>
            <td> <input type="text" id="levelofeducation" name="levelofeducation" value="<% out.print(EduDet.get("Level_of_Education")); %>" /></td>
            <td> <input type="text" id="college_name"  name="college_name" value="<% out.print(EduDet.get("College_Name_OR_School_Name")); %>" /></td>
            <td> <input type="text" id="university_name" name="university_name" value="<% out.print(EduDet.get("University_Name_OR_Board_Name")); %>" /></td>
            <td> <input type="text" id="yearofpassing" name="yearofpassing" value="<% out.print(EduDet.get("Year_of_Passing")); %>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <%} %>  
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My model **JSP** is looks like

```
employee_data1.put("level_of_education",request.getParameterValues("levelofeducation"));
employee_data1.put("college_name" ,request.getParameterValues("college_name"));
employee_data1.put("university_name",request.getParameterValues("university_name"));
employee_data1.put("year_of_passing",request.getParameterValues("yearofpassing"));
```

Finally my **controller** is as

```
try 
{
    SQL = "INSERT INTO education_details(Level_of_Education,College_Name_OR_School_Name,University_Name_OR_Board_Name,Year_of_Passing) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ? );";

    pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(SQL);
    String[] level_of_education = (String[]) employeeData1.get("level_of_education");
    for(String s : level_of_education) 
    {
        pstmt.setString(1, s);
    }

    System.out.println(employeeData1.get("level_of_education"));
    String[] college_name = (String[]) employeeData1.get("college_name");
    for(String c : level_of_education) 
    {
        pstmt.setString(2, c);
    }   

    String[] university_name = (String[]) employeeData1.get("university_name");
    for(String u : university_name) 
    {
        pstmt.setString(3, u);
    }

    String[] year_of_passing = (String[]) employeeData1.get("year_of_passing");
    for(String y : year_of_passing) 
    {
        pstmt.setString(4, y);
    }

    record = pstmt.executeUpdate();
    pstmt.close();
    connection.close();
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're overwriting the parameters for the statement but execute it only once. Instead execute the statement for each employee (or better add a batch - see JDBC docs for that) and before that set the parameters for that single employee.

Comment: Each employee should have a list of education details. For same employee i have to save all his rows data on his employee_id. I am able to save only the last row data by the above code.

Comment: That's because you execute the statement only once but overwrite the parameters first - so the last set parameter will be used. Instead, execute the statement for each set of parameters. You're basically doing `foreach( param1 ) { stmt.setParameter(...); } foreach( param2 ) { stmt.setParameter(...); } stmt.execute();` but you'd need `forEach( paramSet) { stmt.setParameter(param1); stmt.setParameter(param2); stmt.execute(); }` (note: this is pseudo code, the exact syntax is left for you).

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `executeUpdate` statement within loop or you can use batch update something like this..

```
stm = db.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO ITEM (ID, TYPE, TITEL, UITGELEEND) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"); 
db.setAutoCommit(false); 
for (int n = 0; n < ItemLijst.getItems().size(); n++) 
{ 
    Item huidigItem = ItemLijst.getItemObvIdx(n); 
    stm.setString(1, huidigItem.getID().toString()); 
    stm.setString(2, huidigItem.getType().toString()); 
    stm.setString(3, huidigItem.getTitel()); 
    stm.setString(4,String.valueOf(huidigItem.isUitgeleend())); 
    stm.addBatch(); 
} 
stm.executeBatch(); 
db.commit();
```